# In Visual Studio Code 2017: msbuild : The term 'msbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

```
 msbuild : The term 'msbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
 function, script file, or operable program.
```

As far as my googling goes, Visual Code should come with MSbuild. I have installed the C/C++ and msbuild Tools extensions to no avail. What can I do?

Edit: I am using Visual Studio Code 1.19.2

Comment: Seems like a PATH problem perhaps?  Install again with Administrator rights perhaps?

Comment: reinstall Visual Code?

Comment: Reinstall everything LOL...No, only the package with msbuild links in it...VS Code ... Did you enforce Administrator when you installed?

Comment: I had no option to enforce administrator. I wasn't running VC in administrator mode though, I think.

Comment: Its not an 'option'...You must Run As Admin when you  launch the install...You are using Windows OS I hope. Otherwise I'm totally wrong

Comment: I've reinstalled VSCode and relaunched it as administrator, reinstalled all packages and rebooted my computer, I am still having the same problem. At this point I think I will just install msbuild separately.

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak Have I answered your question? If so, please check it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you rethink you command-line approach.

**Short plan**

1. Install Visual Studio Build Tools 2017
2. Find proper MSBuild
3. Use it

---

**Details**

1. Using Build Tools will give you independence from Visual Studio installation.

   Download [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15) from [Visual Studio Downloads page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) ([direct link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/3/7/C37763CB-E533-4290-BE34-1DF89C218CFE/vs_BuildTools.exe))

   Command-line arguments documented here: [Use command-line parameters to install Visual Studio 2017](http://Use%20command-line%20parameters%20to%20install%20Visual%20Studio%202017)

   All workloads and components are listed here: [Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 component directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools)
2. You can use PowerShell module `VSSetup`. Download it or install from here: [Github: Microsoft/Visual Studio Setup PowerShell Module](https://github.com/Microsoft/vssetup.powershell)
3. Run MSBuild with `build` target (you can add additional required parameters)

---

```
# 1. Find MS Build  

Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\VSSetup\VSSetup.psd1

$msBuildPath = (Get-VSSetupInstance | Select-VSSetupInstance -Version 15.0 -Product Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools).InstallationPath

if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 8)
{
    $global:msbuildPath = Join-Path $msBuildPath 'MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64'
}
else
{
    $global:msbuildPath = Join-Path $msBuildPath 'MSBuild\15.0\Bin'
}

Write-Output "Using MSBuild from $global:msbuildPath"
Write-Output "MSBuild /version"

$msbuild = Join-Path $global:msbuildPath msbuild

& $msbuild /version

# 2. Build

& $msbuild "$sln_file" /t:Build /v:q /nologo
```

Answer (score 10):

Likely it's a path issue.  If you have VS2017 installed, it's probably in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

Try adding that to your path, then restart VS Code and try again.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code, I don't have a Microsoft Visual Studio folder and Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin doesn't contain MSBuild. ):

There is, however, an MSBuild folder in my Program Files folder.

Should I just reinstall visual studio code? I am very concerned since googling reveals that nobody has had this problem.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas? ):

Comment: Sorry - late to the reply. Seems like you solved the path problem for MSBuild. What are the other issues now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is a good solution, but it's what I hacked together since the other suggestions didn't work. I installed Visual Studio Installer and installed MSBuild through that. I am having other issues now but at least msbuild is running.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, what worked with me was to use dotnet instead of msbuild :
dotnet build

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

place your jupyter file next to your libs and simply change your current working directory to where your local files are.

```py
import os
os.chdir("/mnt/f/projects/taki/chameleon_cluster")
```

working example

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir("/mnt/f/projects/taki/chameleon_cluster")
print(os.getcwd())
from visualization import *
from chameleon import *


# get a set of data points
df = pd.read_csv('./datasets/Aggregation.csv', sep=' ',
                    header=None)

# returns a pands.dataframe of cluster
res = cluster(df, 7, knn=20, m=40, alpha=2.0, plot=False)

# draw a 2-D scatter plot with cluster
plot2d_data(res)
```

[image]